Sennheiser Presence not pairing with Linux Mint 21.2
I have a Sennheiser Presence earpiece that I've successfully paired with Android and macOS devices.
However, it's not pairing on Linux Mint.  It's invisible to blueman-manager, and when I attempt to use command-line tools, it can be scanned but is never available:
$ hcitool -i hci0 scan
Scanning ...
        00:16:94:35:E7:63       Presence
~/radiopaedia/Radiopaedia (develop) $ bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# trust 00:16:94:35:E7:63
Device 00:16:94:35:E7:63 not available
[bluetooth]# connect 00:16:94:35:E7:63
Device 00:16:94:35:E7:63 not available

It's seemingly just this device, too.  I have a range of other Bluetooth headsets including TOZO and PineBuds, and they work exactly as expected.
Anyone else experienced this & have an idea why it might not be working?

Start by properly updating your OS. Troubleshoot from there
